# when anonymous type is used the List<> object contained in the anonymous type returns null in ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework

I have a strange issue in my code-first entity framework application. Normally, if I have the following code, I can get a specific Post attached with CommentsAssociated correctly in ajax.

```
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        var post= db.Posts.Include(po=>po.CommentsAssociated).Include(po => po.Person)
            .Single(p => p.PostId == postId)
            .AsNoTracking();
```

However, If I use the following code (and I have to), I get no value for CommentsAssociated in ajax.

```
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        IEnumerable<Post> post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId == postId)
                           .Include(p => p.Person)
                           .Include(p => p.CommentsAssociated)
                           .Include(p => p.PostBookmarks)
                           .Include(p => p.PostLikes)
                           .ToList().Select(p => new Post
        {
            PostId = p.PostId,
            Title = p.Title,
            Content = p.Content,
            DatePosted = p.DatePosted,
            Person = p.Person,
            CommentsAssociated = p.CommentsAssociated,
            IsLikedByCurrentUser = p.PostLikes.Select(pl => pl.UserId).Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            IsBookmarkedByCurrentUser = p.PostBookmarks.Select(pb => pb.BookmarkedBy).Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            NoOfComments = p.CommentsAssociated.Count()
        });

        var returnpost = post.FirstOrDefault();
        return returnpost;
```

In both cases, I have valid CommentsAssociated in VS debugging mode. However, I just cannot get CommentsAssociated in ajax, it has no value in ajax. Here is the related section of Post class:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> CommentsAssociated { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the related section of Ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/api/post/GetPostWithFullDetails?postId=' + postId,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (post) {

                $("#pnl_DisplayPostDetails.posttitle").html(post.Title);
                $("#pnl_DisplayPostDetails.postcontent").html(post.Content);

                if (post.CommentsAssociated.length) {
                    //other code
```

UPDATE
When I serialize post object in the controller and return it :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);
```

I still have the same problem win json string format as you can see in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Are you sending down the returned value from server in Json format? From the code above it looks like you are just returning the server object.

Comment: @Dinesh I tried, still the same issue, please see the update.